# Count of visible rows in Ext.dataview.NestedList

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

how to find the count of visible rows in a Ext.dataview.NestedList ?

i tried to do so:

```
this.getItems().length 
and
this.getList(this.getLastNode()).getViewItems().length
```

does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `this.getActiveItem().getItemCount()`.

Nested list is a card container so `this.getItems()` would return the items of the container instead of the items of the dataview list.